# Is it time to update the rules for questions about game consoles?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question was almost directly closed:

[How is it possible that the NPC party members in Breath of Fire III for PlayStation often "get stuck"?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17521/how-is-it-possible-that-the-npc-party-members-in-breath-of-fire-iii-for-playstat)

These questions are still open:

[What data compression did Donkey Kong Country use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17541/what-data-compression-did-donkey-kong-country-use)

[Did the Saturn fail because of game distribution issues?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17516/did-the-saturn-fail-because-of-game-distribution-issues)

[Why didn't SNES Doom use mode 7?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17526/why-didnt-snes-doom-use-mode-7)

[Did the Nintendo S-SMP really contain 3 million transistors?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/did-the-nintendo-s-smp-really-contain-3-million-transistors)

Is the first question closed by mistake, or is it an oversight that the rest of them still are open?
If the first one is correctly closed, I think someone needs to write a explanation why that question isn't according to the rules, but the rest are.

Comment: Interestingly, that question has more re-open votes than close votes closed it (though taking into account the re-open review, there are still more close votes).

Comment: The 'Saturn' question seems to be a question about distribution, not about retrogaming hardware or software.  So I'd say, yeah, that one is off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

The line good game console questions lies between what are bugs in software and what are techniques used on older consoles to wring more out of them. Some of the later PlayStation games wrung a lot more out of the console, the way clever programming got Wolfenstein 3D to run on the SNES. I think that the closed question was a poor question about software quality instead of about techniques. I'm a regular on Stack Overflow so I deal with a lot of bugs and *features* in software.

Comment: Right - the gist was "debug this behavior from some old code".

Answer (score 2):

Different people may have different cut off period for retro; this PlayStation game is from 1997.

However, I suspect that several people are voting to close because the question is not very high quality, rather than down voting instead. Questions can be off topic and good quality or on topic and poor quality.

I suggest the question is poor quality because it is very specific, and also difficult to answer without a lot of inside knowledge. I suspect that any answer would not be very interesting, but I am not trying to criticise the questioner, a new user to the site.

I think the question should be permitted, but left to die of natural causes. I have voted to reopen accordingly.

Comment: I have attempted an edit of the question, and offered an answer now that it is reopened.

Comment: That is indeed a useful generalisation of the question, and thus a good demonstration as to whether this type of question (about 1990s path-finding AI) is appropriate for this site. It shows that it may well be more helpful to develop and improve a poor quality question than to just shut it down, unless it is completely out of scope or deliberately inappropriate.